# Spring data oData filters from pageable are getting ignored when where clause is specified

Tags: java, odata, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have my data model as follows:

```
public class Operation {

   @Column(length = Defaults.MAX_NAME_LENGTH, nullable = false)
   private String name;

   @Column(length = Defaults.MAX_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH, nullable = true)
   private String description;


   @Column(name = "external_id", updatable = false, nullable = false, length = Defaults.MAX_BINDING_ID_LENGTH)
   private String externalId;

   @Column(name = "is_entitleable", nullable = false)
   private boolean entitleable = true;

   }
```

I am using Spring data and my repository OperationRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository. In order to retrieve all the operations, I am using findAll() method with pageable (which has filter information as well). I 'm getting right data.

Filters along with limit 9:

```
externalId eq 'Start' or externalId eq 'Resume' or externalId eq 'Play' or externalId eq 'DestroyPermanent' or externalId eq 'Decommission' or externalId eq 'SoftDestroy' or externalId eq 'harddestroy' or externalId eq 'archive' or externalId eq 'changelease'
```

The generated query

```
select op0_.id as id2_17_, op0_.appears_after_id as appears20_17_, op0_.description as descript3_17_, op0_.is_entitleable as is_entit4_17_, op0_.external_id as external5_17_ from cat_resourceoperation op0_ where op0_.external_id='Start' or op0_.external_id='Resume' or op0_.external_id='Play' or op0_.external_id='DestroyPermanent' or op0_.external_id='Decommission' or op0_.external_id='SoftDestroy' or op0_.external_id='harddestroy' or op0_.external_id='archive' or op0_.external_id='changelease' limit $1","parameters: $1 = '9'
```

I would like to define a query to find all elements where entitleable = true.

```
@Query("select o from operation o where o.entitleable = true) ")
Page<Operation> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

But, in this case the query is completely ignoring my filters. The generated query is -

```
select op0_.id as id2_17_, op0_.appears_after_id as appears20_17_, op0_.description as descript3_17_, op0_.is_entitleable as is_entit4_17_, op0_.external_id as external5_17_ from cat_resourceoperation op0_ where op0_.is_entitleable=true limit $1","parameters: $1 = '9'
```

I have tried naming the methods as findByEntitleable(boolean entitleable, Pageable pageable). But that also didn't work.

Comment: Just add a filter `entitleable` with value `true` to your filter. Also the second will work if you pass in a boolean when calling the query method, currently you are trying to do a find by with a property but never pass in that property, so it tries to use the `Pageable` instead of a boolean value.

Comment: >> Just add a filter entitleable with value true to your filter.  << I don't want that as filters are coming from user input and I would like to filter results always by entitlealble = true.

Comment: In your controller add `entitleable`  to the `Pageable` your are creating.

Comment: >>  currently you are trying to do a find by with a property but never pass in that property, so it tries to use the Pageable instead of a boolean value. << It is ignoring just filters from my query and not entitleable. I'm passing entitleable thought. Updated my question.

Comment: @M. Deinum - I would like to do this at query level only. I would like to restrict my results to entitleable = true at repository layer.

Comment: No you are not. `Pageable` will not work with a `@Query` as you are passing in the query this isn't going to be used as a base query!. You cannot do it at the repository level you will have to pass the property with the value.

Comment: Thank much @M.Deinum. Do you know why it is not working - findByEntitleable(boolean entitleable, Pageable pageable). It should work with filters, right ?

Comment: If you call it like `findByEntitleable(true, pageable)` it should work, when returning a `List` or `Page` from the method.

Comment: Page<Operation> findByEntitleable(boolean entitleable, Pageable pagingInfo); still not honoring filters from pageable like it is doing for findAll (as mentioned in question). Here, the generated query is:  select op0_.id as id2_17_, op0_.appears_after_id as appears20_17_, op0_.description as descript3_17_, op0_.is_entitleable as is_entit4_17_, op0_.external_id as external5_17_ from cat_resourceoperation op0_ where op0_.is_entitleable=$1 limit $2","parameters: $1 = 't', $2 = '9'

Comment: And you don't have a `@Query`? Then remove the method and simply add the filter to your pageable...

Comment: I don't have @Query. I cannot add this boolean to filter.

Comment: Please show us the code you are using, because the `Pageable` implementation you are using is apparently something you provided yourself or you aren't telling the full story.